# Iterate Through Array And Dynamically Add Values To HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html

Using the code below, I am getting divs with class 'post' from an external HTML file and print them to the posts page. Everything shown below works as it should be, however I would like to supplement the code with some automation. More precisely, instead of having hard coded values in the arrays I want to pass variable which were obtained by iterating through all divs with the needed class. Could you please help to implement such action. Thanks in advance.

PHP

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$post = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'post')]");

$array = iterator_to_array($post);
?>
```

HTML posts page

```
<div><?php  echo $doc->saveHTML($array[0]);?></div>
<div><?php  echo $doc->saveHTML($array[1]);?></div>
<div><?php  echo $doc->saveHTML($array[2]);?></div>
```

HTML external file

```
<div class="post">
    post 1 
</div>      
<div class="post">
    post 2 
</div>      
<div class="post">
    post 3
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear: *instead of having hard coded values in the arrays*: which arrays? The only hard-coded literal in your code is the XPath query, but that is not an array, so I don't understand what you want.

Comment: means instead of `post 1` in html, you want dynamic php variable? can you elaborate ?

Comment: Instead of having this $array[0];$array[1];$array[2] I want to have this $array[$some_variable] :)

Comment: @EmilGurbanov can you check my updated answer if it solves your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your question .. is this what u wanted ?

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
 echo "<div> $value </div>";
```

OR

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
 echo "<div> ".$doc->saveHTML($value)." </div>";
```

### Update

If you are looking for a function [Askd in comments]

```
function printdiv($value){
 echo "<div> ".$doc->saveHTML($value)." </div>";
}
```

then call it from wherever you want eg. via foreach loop

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
 printdiv($value);
```

Comment: This actually works, but is there any way to have the divs hard coded and pass the $value to each of them?

Comment: So I don't want the divs will be created dynamically as well, because the post will contain lots of different elements in the main post div, so I just need to have a string of php in it, if I explain clear :)

Comment: @Aamir don't use function name as [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

Comment: @aamir instead of `echo` in the function, use `return`.

Comment: @jigar that was a typo , i mentioned printdiv while calling but mentioned print in function declaration .. anyways updated, thanks...  Emil glad it worked!

Comment: @Aamir yes, I did the echo change to return :) Thanks again!